# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a header with a Sticky effect, but I'm having this error when scrolling the page, sometimes it works and sometimes the error happens. Can anyone help me with this problem?

[image]

```
  const EventPage: React.FC = () => {
    const [isSticky, setSticky] = useState(false);
    const ref = useRef(null);

    const handleScroll = () => {
      if (ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().y <= -580 || null) {
        console.log(ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().y);

        setSticky(true);
      } else {
        setSticky(false);
      }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", () => handleScroll);
      };
    }, []);

    return (
      <div>
        <Head>
          <title>Event Page</title>
        </Head>
        <Header />
        <div className={`sticky-wrapper${isSticky ? " sticky" : ""}`} ref={ref}>
          {isSticky && <Sticky />}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

refs can be null on rerenders therefore always null check before accesssing properties of elements refs. Here is what [gaearon](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11258#issuecomment-337379350) has to say about refs.

```js
const handleScroll = () => {
      if(!ref.current) return
      if (ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().y <= -580 || null) {
        console.log(ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().y);

        setSticky(true);
      } else {
        setSticky(false);
      }
    };
```

Comment: when ref.current is falsy, code should not have proceed. Can you please check why is it going ahead when it should have returned in case of falsy ref.current.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for writing late.

```
if(status: solved)
{
  **CONGRATULATIONS**
}

else{
```

Well, I guess the problem is not in your JS file, maybe it is in your .html file. Go there and either use defer where u linked your JS file or put it under your targeted element.
That might work, at least it did for me!
`}`